# Swift 4.2: Overriding 'restoreUserActivityState' must be as available as declaration it overrides

Tags: ios, swift, siri

I'm trying to implement Siri Shortcuts. To handle them I have to override the `restoreUserActivityState` function, but when I override it into my class which inherits from `UIViewController`, it results into this error: "Overriding 'restoreUserActivityState' must be as available as declaration it overrides". I tried to make my class and my function public but the error persists. Any idea how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example of the code that doesn't compile?

Answer (score 0):

When you override a overridden method from a superclass, you make sure that, you are setting method in the subclass with higher access level than the superclass you inherit from. You can use **open** keyword.

Example:

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController {
    override func restoreUserActivityState(_ activity:NSUserActivity) {

    }
}

class ViewController2: ViewController1 {
    open override func restoreUserActivityState(_ activity: NSUserActivity) {

    }
}
```

I Hope, it solves your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, It didn't work. I have no idea why since your code example perfectly works.